# In Java Spring, How to create an endpoint that consumes a dynamic types of parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to create an API endpoint that consumes a parameter that has dynamic types.

The received JSON parameter may look like either of the following:

```js
{
  entityType: "A",
  createList:[
      {row: 1, name: "sted", department:"drulp"}, 
      {row: 2, name: "mary", department:"kko"}, 
  ],
   updateList:[
      {row: 3, name: "sddf", department:"fff"}, 
      {row: 4, name: "few", department:"kko"}, 
  ]
}
```

```js
{
  entityType: "B",
  createList:[
      {firstName: "John", phone: "0412345678", country:"USA"}, 
      {firstName: "Mary", phone: "0412247474", country:"CANADA"}, 
  ],
   updateList:[
      {firstName: "Tim", phone: "0412345678", country:"Australia"}, 
      {firstName: "Luke", phone: "042728282", country:"CANADA"}, 
  ]
}
```

From above example, we could see that different `entityType` may have different type of `createList` and `updateList`.

Now I am creating an api endpoint to receive these Json data. My code is like the following:

Controller

```java
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/import")
public void executeImport(@RequestBody ImportRequest<? extends ImportModel> request) {
    // some codes...
}
```

The `ImportRequest` class:

```java
public class ImportRequest<T extends ImportModel>  {
    private String entityType;
    private List<T> createList;
    private List<T> updateList;
```

The `ImportModel` class:

```java
public abstract class ImportModel {
}
```

The `ImportTypeAModel` class:

```java
public class ImportTypeAModel extends ImportModel {
    private Integer row;
    private String name;
    private String department;
    // Getters and Setters
}
```

The `ImportTypeBModel` class:

```java
public class ImportTypeBModel extends ImportModel {
    private String firstName;
    private String phone;
    private String country;
    // Getters and Setters
}
```

However, when I call the API, It shows the following messages:

```
Cannot construct instance of `com.core.domain.ImportModel` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 44] (through reference chain: com.core.domain.ImportRequest["createList"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

How can I create the endpoint to consume these dynamic type parameters?

Comment: May be you shoud try using concrete classes and overloading in you controller?!

Comment: Hi @DimitriSifoua, Thank you for your suggestion. However, I have one concern is that in the future, there will be more `entityType` coming into the project(such as TypeC, TypeD, TypeE...). I am afraid that creating overloading method may end up with so many methods in the controller, and  it may not be a good practice.

Comment: You can also use a custom deserializer by annotating your abstract class `ImportModel` with `@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")` and 
`@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ImportTypeAModel.class, name = "A"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ImportTypeBModel.class, name = "B")
})`. This way, Jackson will ba allowed to deserialize the objects into the correct subclasses. However, you will still need to add a `JsonSubTypes` for any new subclass.

Comment: I forgot to mention that in addition to custom deserializer, you to explicitly tell Jackson with subclass you want to use. Please my answer below. It didn't because you need to add a property `type` to each element in the list describing the subclass you want to use. That'w is the purpose of `property = "type"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do:

```java
@Data
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ImportTypeAModel.class, name = "A"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ImportTypeBModel.class, name = "B")
})
public abstract class ImportModel {
}

@Data
@ToString
public class ImportTypeAModel extends ImportModel {
    private Integer row;
    private String name;
    private String department;
}

@Data
@ToString
public class ImportTypeBModel extends ImportModel {
    private String firstName;
    private String phone;
    private String country;
}

@Data
@ToString
public class ImportRequest<T extends ImportModel> {
    private String entityType;
    private List<T> createList;
    private List<T> updateList;
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/import")
    public void executeImport(@RequestBody ImportRequest<? extends ImportModel> request) {
        System.out.println(request.toString());
    }
}
```

Consume the api endpoint:

```http
###
POST http://localhost:8080/import
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "entityType": "A",
  "createList": [
    {
      "type": "A",
      "row": 1,
      "name": "sted",
      "department": "drulp"
    },
    {
      "type": "A",
      "row": 2,
      "name": "mary",
      "department": "kko"
    }
  ],
  "updateList": [
    {
      "type": "A",
      "row": 3,
      "name": "sddf",
      "department": "fff"
    },
    {
      "type": "A",
      "row": 4,
      "name": "few",
      "department": "kko"
    }
  ]
}
# ImportRequest(entityType=A, createList=[ImportTypeAModel(row=1, name=sted, department=drulp), ImportTypeAModel(row=2, name=mary, department=kko)], updateList=[ImportTypeAModel(row=3, name=sddf, department=fff), ImportTypeAModel(row=4, name=few, department=kko)])

###
POST http://localhost:8080/import
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "entityType": "B",
  "createList": [
    {
      "type": "B",
      "firstName": "John",
      "phone": "0412345678",
      "country": "USA"
    },
    {
      "type": "B",
      "firstName": "Mary",
      "phone": "0412247474",
      "country": "CANADA"
    }
  ],
  "updateList": [
    {
      "type": "B",
      "firstName": "Tim",
      "phone": "0412345678",
      "country": "Australia"
    },
    {
      "type": "B",
      "firstName": "Luke",
      "phone": "042728282",
      "country": "CANADA"
    }
  ]
}

# ImportRequest(entityType=B, createList=[ImportTypeBModel(firstName=John, phone=0412345678, country=USA), ImportTypeBModel(firstName=Mary, phone=0412247474, country=CANADA)], updateList=[ImportTypeBModel(firstName=Tim, phone=0412345678, country=Australia), ImportTypeBModel(firstName=Luke, phone=042728282, country=CANADA)])
```

I tested it and it works!